# prepositions tag has an explanation restricting its use to a non-obvious subset

Tags: discussion, tags

The explanation text currently states, that the tag *prepositions* should only be used for **spatial** or **temporal** prepositions. Given the amount of questions related to prepositions (requiring certain cases for the concerned noun) and no other nearby alternative tag, I'm asking for historical reasons for that restriction.

Should we generalize the existing tag to cover modal and causal prepositions as well or add a new tag?

Current questions using that tag seem mostly to unaware of the restriction, so some cleanup would be required to align the use with the strict explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any historic reasons, so I'd just say, remove the non-obvious restrictions from the explanations.